# Enable/Disable permissions for installing iOS app via corporate website

Tags: ios, xcode, enterprise, software-distribution, adhoc

I'm developing iOS app for organisation. I want to distribute this app via corporate website only to certain people in a company (and, of course, not using AppStore). I know how to use `Enterprise` and `Ad Hoc` distributions. But I have an issue with permissions – it's not allowed to download this app for everyone – only for accredited employees.

***Question***:

**How can I activate permissions for installing this iOS app via corporate website**?

Comment: You have to control access to the distribution website and/or build user authentication into your app. There is no way to restrict the IPA file to specific users.  It is better to distribute the app via an MDM; that way you can push the app to specific users and the users don't need to manually trust your enterprise certificate. It also provides a simpler way of updating the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to control access to the distribution website and/or build user authentication into your app. There is no way to restrict the IPA file to specific users.

It is better to distribute the app via an MDM; that way you can push the app to specific users and the users don't need to manually trust your enterprise certificate. It also provides a simpler way of updating the provisioning profile, which is required for enterprise apps.